# How to properly use generics on obj-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, generics, nullable, xcode7

With the new xcode7 Apple introduced generics and nullability to Objective-C ( [Developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) )

But it seems to be very different from what we have on swift.

**Nullability:**

```
- (nonnull NSString *)something {
    return nil;
}
```

This should raise a warning! And you can even assign the return value of this method to a `nonnull` variable like:

```
//@property (copy, nonnull) NSString *name

obj.name = [obj something];
```

**Generics:**
Looking this example:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, nonnull) NSMutableArray <UIView *> *someViews;
```

a warning is raised when something different from a UIView is inserted on the array

```
[self.someViews addObject:@"foobar"]; //<- this raises an error
```

but not in this case:

```
self.someViews = [@[@"foobar"] mutableCopy];
```

nor in this case:

```
NSString *str = [self.someViews firstObject];
```

So the question is, I'm using generics and nullability in a wrong way or they are far away from the Swift implementation?

Comment: seems that there is no "properly" usage of generics and nullability. They offer only some warnings in specific case and they are more useful to comunicate the developer's intent.

Comment: I think it should be a feature request as it seems like the kind of things that the static analyser can catch.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.someViews = [@[@"foobar"] mutableCopy];
```

`mutableCopy` is inherited from `NSObject`, where it is declared to return `id`. It is not declared by `NSArray` specifically and `NSArray` des not decide the return type.

```
NSString *str = [self.someViews firstObject];
```

This *does* give a warning for me.